# Python- data of x ticklable is so many

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

When I am using Seaborn to make a graph, the data of x ticklabels is so many  then becomes black and cant see the value. How to solve? I am new of python.

```
sns.catplot(data=df,kind='bar',x='Income',y='NumTotalPurchases',ci=None) ax.set_xticklabels(['0','20000','40000','60000','80000','100000'],rotation = 30)
```

[image]

Comment: I think `x` in your dataframe is a column of strings when it should be numbers.

Comment: Maybe you want a histogram?  `ax = sns.catplot(data=df,x='Income',weights='NumTotalPurchases', bins=np.arange(0, 110001, 10000 )`?

Comment: @johanC good advice but i think you mean `sns.displot(...)`.

Comment: Thx for your help. Yes it is amount and it has different amount of it so you can see the picture, there are many bars. I think I need to simplify, but I dont know how to do and I tried your code but it doesnt work unfortunately

Comment: Let us know if https://matplotlib.org/devdocs/users/faq/howto_faq.html#why-do-i-have-so-many-ticks-and-or-why-are-they-out-of-order makes sense

Answer (score 0):

You could try some binning techniques using pandas qcut and cut.

[qcut/cut](https://regenerativetoday.com/pandas-cut-and-qcut-method-for-data-binning/)